# Capybara and contenteditable

Tags: capybara, contenteditable

How do you use Capybara to test elements with `contenteditable="true"`?

With this spec...

```
scenario "Using valid input" do
  fill_in "name", with: "Zinn"
  click_button "Update"
  expect(page).to have_content("Update successful!")
end
```

... and this eco file...

```
<td id="name" contenteditable="true"><%= @name %></td>
<td><button id="update" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Update</button></td>
```

I get this failing spec...

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "name"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving the problem.

```
feature "Editing", js: true do

  scenario "with valid input" do
    el = find(:xpath, "//div[@contenteditable='true' and @name='name']")
    el.set("Zinn")
    el.native.send_keys(:return)
    expect(page).to have_content("Update successful!")
    expect(page).to have_content("Zinn")
  end

end
```

According to [this thread](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/911) it looks like you should be able to use the `fill_in` helper on contenteditable divs, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with capybara 2.4.1. Checking the text with `el.text` or with `have_content` both show the original text.

Comment: I should add that I'm using phantomjs 1.9.7 and poltergeist 1.5.1

Comment: In Poltergeist JS it will be: `el.native.send_keys(:Enter)`, not `:return`.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 I can do this

```rb
find('.selector').send_keys 'this text gets filled in'
```